# WCF Rest Service only returns hard-coded data to web browser

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf, rest

I am trying to set up a a wcf rest service that just returns a collection of dinosaur entities in order to display them on a web page. The problem with the service is, I can call it's methods and receive both hard-coded test data as well as data from my database for console program testing purposes just fine, but when I try to view the service in browser, I can only receive hard-coded test data, but not the database. When I get data from the database, the service returns a bad request error.When I hard-code the data into the service, I get a nice json object just fine.

Here is my model used with Entity Framework to do the data gathering from a sql database:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Practice.Models
{
    public class Dino
    {
        public int DinoID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public int Health { get; set; }

        public int Stamina { get; set; }

        public int Oxigen { get; set; }

        public int Weight { get; set; }

        public int Damage { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The base class properties are then mapped and transferred to a DTO object to be returned by the service:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Web;

namespace Practice.Services.DataTransferObjects
{
    [DataContract(Name = "DTODino")]
    public class DTODino
    {
        [DataMember]
        public int DinoID { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int Health { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int Stamina { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int Oxigen { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int Weight { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int Damage { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I used Automapper to do this on the service implementation itself by calling the ConvertToDTODinoCollection method, which looks like:

```
private DTODinoCollection ConvertToDTODinoCollection(DinoCollection tempList)
    {
        DTODinoCollection returnList = new DTODinoCollection();
        foreach (Dino d in tempList)
        {
            DTODino tempDino = new DTODino();
            tempDino = Mapper.Map<DTODino>(d);

            returnList.Add(tempDino);
        }
        return returnList;
    }
```

Here is my service contract:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [Description("Gets a collection of dino records from the database.")]
    [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "Dino/Collection")]
    DTODinoCollection GetDinoCollection();
```

And it's implementation code:

```
public DTODinoCollection GetDinoCollection()
    {
        DinoCollection dinoCollection = dal.GetDinoCollection();
        return ConvertToDTODinoCollection(dinoCollection);

        //DTODinoCollection dinoCollection = new DTODinoCollection() { 
        //    new DTODino { DinoID = 1, Name = "test1", Health=10},
        //    new DTODino { DinoID = 2, Name = "test2", Health=11},
        //    new DTODino { DinoID = 3, Name = "test3", Health=12 } 
        //};
        //return dinoCollection;
    }
```

The commented code above are the values that will pass with no problem, but database data will only make it to a call from the console, but not from the web browser.

Finally, here is my service's web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DinoDatabase" connectionString="Data Source=MNLT084; Initial Catalog=DinoStats"  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />

    <!--Endpoint added for help page functionality-->
    <standardEndpoints>
      <webHttpEndpoint>
        <standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="false"></standardEndpoint>
      </webHttpEndpoint>
    </standardEndpoints>
    <!--__________________________________________-->

  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
    To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
    Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
  -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Just to be clear, I have tried and have been able to successfully retrieve the test data across the console and the web browser using Angular js, but as soon as I switch out the data for the data coming from the database, it wont work across the web browser anymore, only the console. Even though the data is being found, loaded, and bound to the objects correctly as far as I can see on the console project in VS.

Am I just missing some small thing?

-UPDATE-

I built a WebAPI layer and used the same EF layer to call SQLand retrieve database information and it works like a charm. Even displays on the front end using angular no problem. Must be some setting in the REST layer I am missing or some small detail I missed. Guess I am sticking to WebAPI on this one.

Answer (score 0):

what happens in You put a breakpoint in " DinoCollection dinoCollection = dal.GetDinoCollection();" does it return the data ? 
Did You try putting a break point in the place where You call automapper ? is the result full ? or empty ?

one more thing you can try - is Launch 'Fiddler'- to see what is the actual traffic being sent from the server to Your console app and also to angular.

I think Chrome also give You the ability to investigate the traffic that angular receives from the webServer (maybe it's agular failing to parse the result ? )

Comment: I have put a break point at that method and can see that the information is populated, assigned to new object with automapper, and returned correctly. The information matches all my database info. No null values that I can see.

Comment: As far as fiddler, I can see the test data flow through just fine as a nice json object collection. As soon as I switchto real data from datasource, it just gives me error code 400 "Bad request", but the service call still works when being invoked from a test console application which is the weird part. I have used the chrome dev tools and I can see the data getting all the way through angular and being displayed on the front end as long as it's the test data, but again as soon as i switch, It cannot load the resource.